# Edit shutdown menu? Add custom entry?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, efi, gnome

[image: Shutdown Menu]

Hey! I have a Dual-Boot System and I want to add a new button to my shutdown menu. If I press <kbd>Windows 10</kbd> it should run these commands:

```
sudo efibootmgr -n 000E
sudo reboot
```

*Or is there a better way to do this?*

**Systems (Grub entries):**

```
- Elementary OS
- Windows 10
```

**`sudo efibootmgr`:**

```
Boot0000  Setup
Boot0001  Boot Menu
Boot0002  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0003  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0004  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0005  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0006* USB CD
Boot0007  USB FDD
Boot0008  ATA HDD0
Boot0009  ATA HDD1
Boot000A* USB HDD
Boot000B  PCI LAN
Boot000D* ubuntu
Boot000E* Windows Boot Manager
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, grub supports rebooting in to a specific OS, so you might want to use that instead. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-tell-grub-i-want-to-reboot-into-windows-before-i-reboot for more details.

To add an extra button would require to edit the source code of Pantheon, which would require that you manually compile Pantheon for every update. An easier way to get a 'Windows 10'-button would be to make a script that automatically configures Grub and reboots. So here's how to do that:

**(CAUTION! If you don't know what this is, don't blindly copy this code!)**

### 1. Make a script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

efibootmgr -n 000E
# OR
grub-reboot '<boot entry name of windows 10>'

reboot
```

### 2. Make a `Windows 10.desktop` file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Windows 10
Comment=Reboot into Windows
Exec=pkexec /path/to/script.sh
```

Move this file to `/usr/local/share/applications` to put it in the application list.

[The freedesktop specification for `*.desktop` files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

### 3. Make the script executable

Run this in a terminal:
`chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`

### 4. Test it.

Double click the `Windows 10.desktop` file and check that it works.